# nifi pyspark - "no module named boto3"

Tags: amazon-s3, pyspark, boto3, apache-nifi, kylo

I'm trying to run a pyspark job I created that downloads and uploads data from s3 using the boto3 library. While the job runs fine in pycharm, when I try to run it in nifi using this template https://github.com/Teradata/kylo/blob/master/samples/templates/nifi-1.0/template-starter-pyspark.xml

The ExecutePySpark errors with "No module named boto3".

I made sure it was installed on my conda environment that is active.

Any ideas, im sure im missing something obvious.

Here is a picture of the nifi spark processor.

[image]

Thanks,
tim

Comment: You need to add that library to all Spark executors in the cluster. It works locally because you have the library available

Comment: Thankyou - im not totally sure how to do that - im just running it on 1 ubuntu vm?

Comment: Okay, in that case, how are you telling Nifi (a Java application) that it needs to activate a specific conda environment?

Comment: Have you configured your `spark-defaults.conf` to use the conda environment that has all the necessary libraries installed? In this case, `boto3`

Comment: I don't think I am - I figured it would just use the active environment

Comment: the spark-defaults.conf - this should be in my spark home?

Comment: My mistake, the field to set the python environment is in `spark-env.sh`. The field is `PYSPARK_PYTHON`

Comment: I can see load-spark-env.sh?

Comment: No.. under `conf` directory, there will be `spark-env.sh`. Edit that

Comment: You the man. Worked a charm.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Python environment where `PySpark` should run on is configured via the `PYSPARK_PYTHON` variable.

- Go to Spark installation directory
- Go to `conf`
- Edit `spark-env.sh`
- Add this line: `export PYSPARK_PYTHON=PATH_TO_YOUR_CONDA_ENV`